# Hosting multiple web apps on GitHub

Tags: github, github-pages

Recently I discovered that we can host our web apps on GitHub and publish them with the repo URL.

I created a repo named *myusername.github.io* and published my web app on it. Now I want to host another web app created in another repo. https://pages.github.com/ says that the hosting won’t work if the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your username.

But now since I already have a repo of that name, how do I create another one and host my web-app there?

I tried to do something like *myusername.github.io-webapp* (where the first part matches my username) but it did not work.

Is there a work around for this or am I just naming my repos incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

For your second app you are wanting to publish, create a new repo using any name (e.g. *myapp*).

Then publish a branch named `gh-pages` to that repo.

Your new app should then be available at `http://USER.github.io/REPO`. So, for our example, `username.github.io/myapp`.

For a detailed guide on these steps, see the [Creating Project Pages Manually](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually) guide.

---

The convention of creating a repo with the pattern `user.github.io` is just a shortcut way of doing the steps above, and only works once since repo names are unique.

But the manual steps above work for any number of repositories!

Answer (score 1):

You get one website per GitHub account, but no one is stopping in you from dividing it between multiple applications. For example you can put one application under `/app1` and another one under `/app2`.

Keep in mind that GitHub is a git hosting company, not a web hosting one.